# How to configure WSO2 AS and WSO2 AM and identity server on the same server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-as

I am trying to run API Manager and Application Server on the same server, along with configuration of Identify Server. I am getting Address already bind exceptions when starting server one after another. Please suggest me, how to configure these servers on the same system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All WSO2 products run on top of WSO2 Carbon framework. Each product will be using a set of [ports](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Default+Ports+of+WSO2+Products) in your system.

So, when you run multiple products in the same server without any configurations changes, you will run in to address already in use exceptions.

To avoid this you can just set a port offset for your products.

Please edit `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml`. Search for `<Offset>`.

Here I'm quoting the [docs](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Configuring+carbon.xml).

> `<Offset>` Ports offset. This entry will set the value of the ports defined below to the define value + Offset. e.g. Offset=2 and HTTPS port=9443 will set the effective HTTPS port to 9445.

Once you give different offsets for each product, you will be able to run multiple products in the same server.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Where can we see the new ports once the offset is applied?

Comment: There is no specific place to see all ports. But the management console or the logs will show you the correct port (after adding the offset) whenever there is a URL.

Comment: btw, when I am  running on my local system I am surprisingly seeing urls mapped with different IP Address, when using the same I am not able to access the application. for e.g.: http://100.101.153.254:9783/pizza-shack-web-1.0.0/ which is not working. And this ip is not my public ip. From where wso2 application taking this ip address?

Comment: WSO2 Carbon takes the address from your system. So, that IP must be there in your configs. Please double check. What are the versions you are using? API Manager 1.5.0?